# Google Analytics & Tag Manager in page with iFrame counting page views and users twice

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

First time working with GA and GTM. I have a `wordpress` site where there is a cross domain iFrame in one of the pages (booking system from external company).

The parent page contains the following:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --> 
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-CODE"></script>
<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
} 
gtag('js', new Date()); 
gtag('config', 'UA-CODE'); 
</script> 

<!-- Google Tag Manager --> 
<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){
     w[l]=w[l]||[];
     w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'
     });
    var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], 
    j=d.createElement(s),
    dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
    j.async=true;
    j.src= 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); 
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-CODE');
</script> 
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

The iFrame page contains:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --> 
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-CODE"></script>
<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
} 
gtag('js', new Date()); 
gtag('config', 'UA-CODE'); 
</script> 

<!-- Google Tag Manager --> 
<script>
(function(w,d,s,l,i){
     w[l]=w[l]||[];
     w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'
     });
    var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], 
    j=d.createElement(s),
    dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
    j.async=true;
    j.src= 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); 
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-CODE', { 'send_page_view': false });
</script> 
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

The only difference being in the iFrame, the GA code contains the following:

```
gtag('config', 'UA-CODE', { 'send_page_view': false })
```

But still in Analytics real time overview, I get 2x users and 2 page views when I access the parent page.

What have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Any chance that either the parent or iframe GTM configuration has a PageView event or hit with interaction=on setup inside the GTM container? This would be something setup inside of GTM and not within the JS  you can see in the page. Easiest way to check is to open the Dev Tools Network Panel and check how requests to `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect` are originating (hover over each row's initiator script to see the stack trace that triggered the pageview).

Comment: Hi @Joshua T. Thanks for tge suggestion. I will check and report back.